# Oracle - impdp - import a partition

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, impdp, datapump

I truncated a partition, and would like to import it from backup.

How can I import a partition from the dump file?

Export log:

```
. . exported "XY_PROD"."XY_LOG_PLSQL"              69.16 MB  320459 rows
. . exported "XY_PROD"."XY_RESPONSE":"SYS_P25129"  2.198 GB   67804 rows
. . exported "XY_PROD"."XY_RESPONSE":"SYS_P26385"  973.4 MB   31742 rows
. . exported "XY_PROD"."XY_RESPONSE":"SYS_P25395"  2.184 GB   88242 rows
. . exported "XY_PROD"."XY_RESPONSE":"SYS_P25891"  3.366 GB  106484 rows
```

Tried:

```
INCLUDE=PARTITION:\"IN \(\'SYS_P25129\'\)\"
INCLUDE=PARTITION:"XY_RESPONSE":"SYS_P25129"
INCLUDE=PARTITION:\"XY_RESPONSE\":\"SYS_P25129\"
```

Getting:

```
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39071: Value for INCLUDE is badly formed.
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
```

The whole table is several GB. If there is a way, I don't want to import whole table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this example](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/datapump-import-utility.html#GUID-E9D822CA-4EF7-4F61-9E88-6E3F25CFEAFC) in the Oracle Docs:

```
TABLES=XY_RESPONSE:SYS_P25129
```

should be sufficient.

Unless you have a very strange collation in your database, no quoting is required for any of these arguments.

Comment: This answer is for `imp`. I am asking for `impdp`

Comment: Almost the same, just without the braces: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/datapump-import-utility.html#GUID-E9D822CA-4EF7-4F61-9E88-6E3F25CFEAFC.

Comment: Thanks @phill-w , if You fix your answer I will accept it

Comment: @Jakub P: Answer fixed; both example and link.